# Android - Content Provider query cursor

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I cannot seem to grasp the concept of Content provider. I personally think that it bloats the code, it over-complicates it, and is plainly awful.

**BTW this will be the first example code of a multi-table ContentProvider that you will find on the web. There is absolutelly NONE other, except for maybe the ContactsProvider ("veeeerrrrry usefull" - by being super-stuffed and indescifrable). I am sure many noobs like me will appreciate this.**

Please help me make a simple cursor from a content provider. I have the NORMAL code bellow (using a simple SQLiteOpenHelper), and I need to translate it into content-provider code:

```
    Button btnp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnproc);
    btnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Context mycontext = getApplicationContext();
        SQLiteDatabase db = new myDbHelper(mycontext).getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "select _id,data,titlu,cont from notificari where date(data)<=date(datetime())";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        Log.w("...MainActivity...", "Record count:"+Integer.toString(curu.getCount()));
            while(curu.moveToNext()){
                String lista = curu.getString(0)+",'"+curu.getString(1)+"',"+curu.getString(2)+",'"+
                        curu.getString(3)+"'";
                Log.e("...MainActivity...", lista);
            }

        }
    });
```

So I need the cursor to be obtained from content-provider. I have already started developing this "mind-blowing" content-provider, but I have no idea if what I am doing is ok, since it is so overcomplicated. Here it goes (my content-provider needs to refference more than one table):

```
public class MyFirstProvider extends ContentProvider {
static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.mystuff.myapp.MyFirstProvider";
    static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/cte";
    static final String URL2 = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/clienti";
    static final String URL3 = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/uzeri";
    static final String URL4 = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/notificari";
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI2 = Uri.parse(URL2);
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI3 = Uri.parse(URL3);
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI4 = Uri.parse(URL4);


    static final int uriCode = 1;
    static final int uriCode1 = 2;
    static final int uriCode2 = 3;
    static final int uriCode3 = 4;
    static final int uriCode4 = 5;
    static final int uriCode5 = 6;
    static final int uriCode6 = 7;
    static final int uriCode7 = 8;


    static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    private static HashMap<String, String> values;
    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cte", uriCode);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cte/*", uriCode1);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "clienti", uriCode2);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "clienti/*", uriCode3);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "uzeri", uriCode4);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "uzeri/*", uriCode5);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "notificari", uriCode6);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "notificari/*", uriCode7);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode:
                qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
                qb.setProjectionMap(values);
                break;
            case uriCode2:
                qb.setTables(TABLE_CLIENTI);
                qb.setProjectionMap(values);
                if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "") {
                    sortOrder = TCL_NUME_CLIENT;
                }
                break;
            case uriCode6:
                qb.setTables(TABLE_NOTIF);
                qb.setProjectionMap(values);
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,null, sortOrder);
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }


    // ... there is other code here regarding the insert,update and delete (not relevant now)

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "names";
    public static final String TABLE_UZERI = "uzeri";
    public static final String TABLE_NOTIF = "notificari";


    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + " name TEXT NOT NULL);";

    static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE_NOTIFICARI = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTIF + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            TNOT_ID_NOT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            TNOT_DATA + " DATE NOT NULL, " +
            TNOT_SURSA + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "+
            TNOT_DEST + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "+
            TNOT_TIP + " TEXT, "+
            TNOT_TITLU + " TEXT, "+
            TNOT_TITLUCONT + " TEXT, "+
            TNOT_CONT + " TEXT, "+
            TNOT_STERS + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "+
            TNOT_NOU + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)";

   private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE_UZERI);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE_NOTIFICARI);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_UZERI);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTIFICARI);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

I tried to "translate" the Activity code that logs the content of the cursor but it just does NOTHING. It's VERY frustrating.
Here is my "translation":

```
Button btnp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnproc);
btnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String[] coloane = {MyFirstProvider.TNOT_ID_ID, MyFirstProvider.TNOT_DATA,MyFirstProvider.TNOT_TITLU, MyFirstProvider.TNOT_CONT};
        Cursor curu = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(MyFirstProvider.CONTENT_URI_NOTIF,coloane,null,null,MyFirstProvider.TNOT_DATA);

        Log.w("...MainActivity...", "Recorduri:"+Integer.toString(curu.getCount()));
        while(curu.moveToNext()){
            String lista = curu.getString(0)+",'"+curu.getString(1)+"',"+curu.getString(2)+",'"+
                    curu.getString(3)+"'";
            Log.e("...MainActivity...", lista);
        }

    }
});
```

I must assure you that the table has 4 records inside (I insert them manually after table creation)
Also if I put this code inside the ContentProvider, then the Log displays the content of the table as desired:

```
Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,null, sortOrder);
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            Log.w("...Provider...",c.getString(0)+"-"+c.getString(1)+"-"+c.getString(2));
        }
```

But I do not want to do this in the content provider, I want to do it in the Activity code.
What am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: First of all, do you need a content-provider?

Comment: Did you figure this one out in the end? Content Providers are another level of abstraction for external access to your data.

When making the queries, it's better to abstract the code to a helper class so that the activity doesn't know about the underlying data access. It will simplify your code significantly and reduce the number of times you have to replicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `ContentProvider` if you don't have to. Identify your requirements. If the data is private to your application AND if it has to be stored in a table format, then you can access SQLite engine directly in Android without having to go via `ContentProvider`. But if you want other apps or system to access your app's data, then yes - that's a legitimate use case for `ContentProvider`.

Nonetheless, i would suggest you read this [article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) - that tells you how to access `SQLite` engine with and without `ContentProvider`.

Hope this helps.

Anyways, for your problem at hand, try this -

```
Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,null, sortOrder);
if (c == null) {
  // error - log some message
}
else if (c.getCount() < 1) {
  // nothing to show  - log some message
}
else {
  while(c.moveToNext()){
    Log.w("...Provider...",c.getString(0)+"-"+c.getString(1)+"-"+c.getString(2));
  } 
}
```

Comment: I HAVE TO, unfortunatelly. Because I need to sync my SQLite db with a remote MySQL DB later... I wish there was a better way than ContenrtProvider. I simply hate it

Comment: Odd... my cursor is not null, however if I do not test it (null or not) apparently it will stop processing code. How nice... Anyway, thanks for the heads-up. You solved my problem. (Of course I am sure you meant that the first if statement should be "if (c == null)" )

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this

```
btnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener
```

try

```
btnp.setOnClickListener(this)
```

and implement onClickListner to the Activity.

In short, instead of casting onClickListener to button, implement it to the whole activity and try.

Comment: You do not understand. My cursor/query gets executed, because I can see the logcat generated by the Provider. But after the cursor is executed, I can also see the LogCat from MainActivity showing the getCount() of the cursor, and then nothing... also I have multiple buttons on the activity so I do not want to implement the litener to the whole activity. Also I do not think that would solve my problem. As I already said, the click event is working, but only partially. The while loop seems to NOT execute

Comment: very unrealistic solution, can not be considered as an answer